# What is 120% of 95th percentile in the chart below?

Tags: charts, statistics, percentile

https://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/data/extended-bmi/BMI-Age-percentiles-GIRLS.pdf

IN this chart above, what is 120% of 95th percentile indicate? Isn't it supposed to be 99th percentile?
I am trying to understand the chart. I understand the rest of the chart but not sure what the 120% of 95th percentile means

Comment: No, it's just the 95th percentile multiplied with 1.2. It doesn't mean anything else - it doesn't have a statistical significance by itself. It makes sense to define classes of obesity in multiplicative terms of the 95th percentile, because the relationship between the classes should be *linear* - that is 120% BMI of the obesity level should always define severe obesity and 140% always class 3 obesity, *regardless of age*. If they chose for instance 98th percentile for class 2 and 99th percentile for class 3 the BMI ratio between these levels would have varied with age.